# BrightSign JavaScript: How to debug code running on embedded Chromium renderer

Tags: javascript, chromium, remote-debugging, brightscript

I recently created an HTML bulletin board page intended to run on a series of BrightSign display units.

It is written in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. The data being displayed is pulled from an API over HTTP that returns JSON.

For development, I downloaded the same version of Chromium that BrightSign indicates is included in the firmware version of our devices to render the HTML on the BrightSign.

My code runs perfectly in the web browser, and when I upload it to the BrightSign, the HTML and CSS seem to function as expected, and I can see the JavaScript runs - several HTML elements are modified by the code as expected.

However, some of the data fields that work fine in the browser for testing are not updating, so the code is not behaving as expected when being run on the BrightSign.

I need to know how to debug the code as it is running on the BrightSign - I can't debug it on the test browser, since it runs fine there. I read BrightSign's HTML5 best practices, and don't see anything there that might point to why the code isn't running as expected.

I followed the directions at https://brightsign.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOC/pages/370672286/HTML+Best+Practices#Debugging-Webpages to try to use the Chrome remote debugging to debug the code as it runs on the BrightSign and see what errors are actually causing the problem, but I can't seem to get it to work - after following all the directions there, the console never connects, seeming to indicate the remote debugging isn't actually running on the BrightSign.

I need to either find out how to get the remote debugging working to get at the problem from that angle, or another method of debugging the code on the BrightSign.